# Making a whole div change over hover

Tags: html, css

I have the image hover working properly, but it only changes color once it's hovered over. Like, I want the div once hovered, it'll change the image.

I don't want to hover over the image itself and it only changes, which is what it's doing.

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation-box">                                    
        <div class="sidehead"><i class="lock"></i>header 1</div>                                
            <div class="navLinks">
                <ul class="">
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>          
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lock {
    background: url('../images/lock.png') no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-left:5%;
}

li:hover .lock{
    background: url("../images/lock-hover.png") no-repeat center;    
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfwupc7v/)

In the fiddle, you'll see what I'm talking about. I simply want the div `sidehead` once hovered over, to change the `lock` image. Any ideas what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The replacement image is white on white...so you can't see it - http://jsfiddle.net/acvLkepv/

Comment: Let me clarify. Do you want it to permanently change after the hover? Such that if you mouse out of the element it still is the white image?

Comment: I know. That's not what I was talking about though, haha! I'm trying to have it to where I hover over "header 1" and the image will change. It doesn't do that. I have to go to the image itself to see the image change. I want to be able to hover anywhere over the div and it'll change that image.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek the whole hover works correct. I'm not worried about that. It when I hover over the div it self, the image doesn't change. I have to hover over the actual image to get it to change to white.

Comment: So when you hover over the div with the class `navigation-box` you want the image to change? But still act like a normal hover where it goes back to normal when you leave the div?

Comment: actually yes @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: Looking to do this?      http://jsfiddle.net/tfwupc7v/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the selector slightly wrong.

If you want something to happen when you hover over the `.sidehead` div, that where you have to put the hover

```css
.sidehead .lock {
    background: url('http://uploadir.com/u/il2433z4') no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-left:5%;
}
.sidehead:hover .lock {
    background: grey url("http://uploadir.com/u/4js58y48") no-repeat center;
}
.sidehead {
    border:1px solid green; /* for visual refernece */
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-box">
    <div class="sidehead"><i class="lock"></i>header 1</div>
    <div class="navLinks">
        <ul class="">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because [CSS can't select a parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). Your CSS reads as when you hover over the list item, the child .lock will do something. This is where jQuery comes in. You can write something like this:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
  $('.lock').addClass('newClass');
});
```

CSS:

```
.newClass {
  background: url("../images/lock-hover.png") no-repeat center;  
}
```

This is just an example and doesn't include when you hover outside of the list but it should help move things along.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript. So you can use the `mouseout` and `mouseover` events to work as a hover:

```
$(".navigation-box").mouseover(function(){ // White image
    $(".lock").css("background"," url('http://uploadir.com/u/4js58y48') no-repeat center")
});
$(".navigation-box").mouseout(function(){ // Black image
    $(".lock").css("background"," url('http://uploadir.com/u/il2433z4') no-repeat center")
});
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/acvLkepv/1/). Note I changed the background color of the body so the change is obvious.

Or you can do:

```
.navigation-box:hover > .sidehead > .lock {
    background: url("http://uploadir.com/u/4js58y48") no-repeat center;  
}
```

[For example](http://jsfiddle.net/acvLkepv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using jQuery

I would advice to give your li a class (or your ul)

```
$('li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.lock').trigger(e.type);
});
```

This code will trigger the hover event for every .lock object when an li is hovered (add id's and or classes if you want to make it a bit more precise but that should be pretty straight forward)